# App crash on startup, not in Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3

I’ve been working on an app that crashes from time to time on startup. When I use Xcode to start it on the iphone for diagnosis the app works fine, and I have no way to debug what when wrong as it seem to happend only when running from the phone. 
What way do I have to see what caused the crash ?

Thanks.

Comment: Does your app using database? it'll help you so much if you add crash log to your app(like crashlytics,...).

Comment: Try integrating fabric and see the crash in crashlytics

Comment: No database. Just calendar loading and few views. I will look into crashlytics thanks. Never heard of that.

Comment: do you use any library?

Comment: No particular library. I just load events from the calendar and display data in a text view.

Comment: Add this to the app:  https://fabric.io/kits/ios/crashlytics   and get the logs.

Comment: Hello again. I did add crashlytics to the app, the setup went well and I can see some stats, but unfortunately my app started crashing again after few days and it didn't report anything.